# ¿Cómo comparar dentro de un if un índice de un arreglo con un arreglo completo?

Tags: c#, array

Lo que quiero realizar es la comparacion de un indice con un arreglo completo (con todos sus indices). Esto quiere decir que yo voy a necesitar saber si el indice de mi primer arreglo esta en cualquiera de los indices del segundo arreglo.

Ejemplo:

```
if (AduanaOriginal[0] == registro && PatenteOriginal[0] == registro && PedimentoOriginal[0] == registro)
{
}
```

Esto se hace con la finalidad de saber si el indice del primer arreglo existe en cualquiera de los indices del segundo arreglo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se puede resolver con **Linq**.

Agregas Using System.Linq; al inicio del archivo y después modificas tu condición:

```
if (AduanaOriginal.Contains(registro) && PatenteOriginal.Contains(registro) && PedimentoOriginal.Contains(registro))
{

}
```

ó si lo que deseas es buscar dentro del arreglo registro el valor de los otros indices haces esto:

```
if (registro.Contains(AduanaOriginal[0]) && registro.Contains(PatenteOriginal[0]) && registro.Contains(PedimentoOriginal[0]))
{

}
```

Comment: Gracias, actualize la respuesta para ese caso tambien.

Comment: Si, lo vi :P por eso borré mi comentario hahah un saludo

Comment: Lo siento se me habia olvidado dar como correcta la respuesta, gracias.

Comment: No pasa nada, @David, un despiste es un despiste. Gracias por la rapida reaccion.

Comment: Hola @DanMiranda me parece que hay una pequeña confusión, el método `Contains` no corresponde a Linq, corresponde al *NameSpace* `System` :)

Comment: El namespace si es System.Linq, pero ya encuentra dentro del ensamblado System.Core.dll https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas la funcion [`contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015.aspx)

> ```
> Array.contains( array, elemento)
> ```
>
> Se busca dentro del *array*, si existe el *elemento* y devuelve `true` o `false`

Ej:

```
if (Array.contains(registro,AduanaOriginal[0]) && Array.contains(registro,PatenteOriginal[0])&& Array.contains(registro,PedimentoOriginal[0]))
{
}
```